# Erlang how to check the first value of command line?

Tags: string, erlang

This following line give me what user has been wrote in Command prompt

```
Y= io:get_line("Send message --> ").
```

My question is, I want to **write a if condition that check if user enter "#$"** **in the line as a first argument** then it shall show some error message.

Any suggestions or comment will be greatly appreciate. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably want to split your arguments:

```
Line = io:get_line("Send message --> "),
Args = string:tokens(Line, [$\s, $\t, $\n]).
```

Now you have list of string arguments, let's use pattern matching:

```
case Args of
    ["#$" | _TailArgs] -> 
        error("some error message");
    Args ->
        do_something_with(Args)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution:

```erlang
case io:get_line("Send message --> ") of
    "#$" ++ _Rest ->
        error(something_wrong);
    Args ->
        work_with(Args)
end.
```